# Gmaps4rails - how to set map language

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'd like to localise the map generated by Gmaps4rails, so I can show place names in the users desired language. Google documents how to do this here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language

I'm using a fairly standard (and currently functional) implementation of Gmaps4rails, which you can see here.

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ 
    provider: { styles: mapStyle }, 
    internal: {id: 'map'}
}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

Rendering to the html...

```
<div class="map-container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

I just need to find out where to define the language code. I've tried adding it as an option to the provider, with no joy (e.g. `provider: { styles: mapStyle, language: 'zh-TW' }`).

I've scoured the documentation (and source), but can't seem to find any info on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to indicate the language in the script.

For example in the **[Maps API v3 Now Speaks Your Language](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/10/maps-api-v3-now-speaks-your-language.html)**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=pt-BR">
```

You can find the list of [languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) here.

Here is the code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Localizing the Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example displays a map with the language and region set
      // to Japan. These settings are specified in the HTML script element
      // when loading the Google Maps JavaScript API.
      // Setting the language shows the map in the language of your choice.
      // Setting the region biases the geocoding results to that region.
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 35.717, lng: 139.731}
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&language=ja&region=JP"
    async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in this code line, `key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&`**`language=ja`**`&region=JP`, language is set to **jp = Japanese**.

Also check their working [sample](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/map_language/map_lang.html) with a dynamic language setting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot, I thought there might be a way to handle this via the gem, but as I can edit the src dynamically in rails I might as well go that way. Thanks for your post.